# export mupdf and android studio 0.5.4

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio, mupdf

First: I want to view pdf files in my android app.
I googled and analyzed and decided to use [mupdf](http://www.mupdf.com/)
For a start I use [this guide](http://mupdf.blogspot.ru/2013/01/compile-mu.html?showComment=1397338430022) to build demo project and it's work fine in eclipse. But I need to run it in Android studio. I try to export from eclipse as gradle project and import to Android Studio. File explorer work, but when I opened pdf I get error:

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.openFile(MuPDFActivity.java:213)
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(MuPDFActivity.java:309)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
 ...
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mupdf: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.<clinit>(MuPDFCore.java:14)
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.openFile(MuPDFActivity.java:213)
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(MuPDFActivity.java:309)
```

I try to just import project without convert it in Eclipse, but when I run application, I get error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\SpeedBoots\android-ndk-r9d\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\mupdf\platform\android\app\build\ndk\debug\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT=C:\mupdf\platform\android\app\build\ndk\debug\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\mupdf\platform\android\app\build\ndk\debug\lib APP_ABI=all
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       make.exe: *** No rule to make target `C:\mupdf\platform\android\app\build\ndk\debug\obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdf/C_\mupdf\platform\android\app\src\main\jni', needed by`C:\mupdf\platform\android\app\build\ndk\debug\obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdf/C_\mupdf\platform\android\app\src\main\jni\mupdf.o'.  Stop.

1. How to add mupdf library to Android Studio and in my project? I will appreciate any link, examples. Any that could help.
2. How to import projects with native code to Android Studio? I'm absolute noob in NDK and scare that I need to read tons of tutorial and books for just import project.

Comment: I exported project from Eclipse as gradle project and success run it in Android studio. The new issue that when I add this project as module to my general app I get    Couldn't load mupdf from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/quentin.math.ege-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/quentin.math.ege-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the errors you are getting seem to indicate that your .so files aren't getting integrated correctly into your APK. You can check that by unzipping your APK and looking inside `lib/armeabi-v7a`, `lib/x86`, etc

If there is only one .c or .cpp source file under `jni/` folder, that may be the cause of this `No rule to make target` error, there is known bug on Windows: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66937

If you run into other troubles with Android Studio and the NDK, I've made an article that may help you here: http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/

Comment: You are right. My apk have no .so files. The problem was in project structure. I move my .so files from libs to src/main/jniLibs and it's work!!